# MS SQL Server Trigger if else insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a trigger but I need help. How can I write this type of trigger?
If data coming null insert into this parameter?
There is my codes

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddDayOn ON Control
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @first DATETIME,@second DATETIME,@name NVARCHAR(11),@birth DATETIME
SELECT @first = First,
       @second = Second,
       @name = Name,
       @birth = Birth
FROM inserted
INSERT INTO Control(
Name,
First,
Birth,
Second,
Prob
)
VALUES
( @name,
@first,
@birth,
DATEADD(DAY,220,@first),
DATEADD(DAY 250,@first))
```

I need to chance this trigger with if-else.Because i have 3 more parameters(Four,Five,Six). I'm try to write something like that

```
 If @first not null DATEADD..
 If @four not null DATEADD.. like that
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  When you ask about SQL or a DBMS, please include the tag for the DBMS — in this case, [tag:sql-server].  Also include your best effort, and an illustrated explanation of what you are doing, or trying to do.  Ideally, that'll be an MCV E ([MCVE]).  As it stands, there isn't enough information here for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use exists in your statement like this:

```
insert into table1(col1,col2)
select col1,col2 from inserted as i 
where not exists(select 0 from table1 where relatedkey=i.relatedkey)
```

Comment: @Oronar I did not get it with my answer, If the data is null what value you want to insert? I think  you only need use ISNULL  to specify a value when the data is null. another think, Is it possible that will  insert multiple lines one time

Comment: ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY,220,@first),'Some default date')